# Ajax back to previous page

Tags: ajax

I have a form inserted by jQuery Ajax to a page's div (say, 'content') and when the user finishes filling the form and hits 'submit' button, the result will be shown for further verification. The html and  ajax code are as follows:

HTML:

```
<form id="userForm" action="..." method="post">
  ...
  ...
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#userForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function(returnData) {
      $('#content').html(returnData);
    }
  });
});
```

The 'returnData' is the filled form (without input fields) for further confirmation. Now, how do I implement a 'back' button such that the user may go back and modify the previously entered data?

I am working on Google App Engine with Python. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I tried to Google around, but found lots of stuff that look very complicated. I hope some one can provide a simpler answer or point to a right direction.

Comment: ok, broadly: you need to save the data server side and reload the form with what data you do have filled in.

Comment: Interesting... So, it is actually not an ajax thing, but simply transmission of data between the sever and client side?

Comment: those two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt response, Colleen. According to your suggestion, this seems to be working: the 'returndata' is inserted into a div using ajax, the field values can be stored using <input type='hidden' ...>. And the 'back' button is just another 'post' to send the data back to the server, followed by rendering a form page with the previous data.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't replace the `form` with new HTML.

I would rather hide the form with `display: none` and add the new HTML for viewing alongside. If you want to go back, then you can just hide the "viewing div" and show again the `form`, without the need to refill any input elements.

Something along these lines should work

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="user-form-container">
        <form id="userForm" ...>...</form>
    </div>

    <div id="viewing-container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#viewing-container {
    display: none;
}
```

The viewing part contains some sort of `back-button`, which hides the viewing area and shows the form again

jQ:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userForm').ajaxForm({
        success: function(returnData) {
            $('#viewing-container').html(returnData);
            $('#user-form-container').hide();
            $('#viewing-container').show();
            $('#viewing-container #back-button').click(function() {
                $('#user-form-container').show();
                $('#viewing-container').hide();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Uh... got the idea, but don't understand technically. Would you elaborate more? Thanks.